# How can I create a duplicate collection (tree structure) using Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My hierarchy of `List` (Schema) is as follows:

```
List -> Items -> (attachments, comments, labels)
```

I want to create another duplicate list (collection) of the existing list. This means, all hierarchical referenced elements should be created (copied). Here `(attachments, comments, labels)` are referenced by `Item` and `Item` is referenced by `List`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's called a "deep copy". I'm not sure what mongoose has to do with it. See this question for JavaScript in general: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)